# Cross filtration using jquery

Tags: jquery, crossfilter

I can not seem to filter my results in several types of queries, Year and Type :

```
$('.filter').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this),
    year = button.attr('data'),
        str_year = '.' + year;
    if (button.hasClass('active')) {
        button.removeClass('active');
        $(str_year).not(":hidden").hide('fast');

    } else {
        button.addClass('active');
        $(str_year).not(":visible").show('fast');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dh3ajyqy/)

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: For example, if I inactive a button of the date 2011 and Science then I reactive the button 2011, there are div with the class `.Science` who appears. I want only div without the class `.Science`. Do you understand me @guest271314 ?

Comment: If interpret correctly , http://jsfiddle.net/dh3ajyqy/ appear to perform this process ? Tried jsfiddle with `2010` and `Science` both `pink` , other buttons `transparent` , only `2010 S` green background element set to `display:inline-block` . Is this expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 : But if after that you press on 2011, you will see different div and this on for example : 2011 C. The thing is that the script does not retain the "Codeur" button is disabled and does not display results containing this tag or it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var filter = $(".filter");
filter.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  filter.map(function(_, el) {
      if ($(el).is(".active")) {
        var year = $(el).attr("data");
        if (!!$("[class^=" + year + "]")) {
          $("[class^=" + year + "]").show(0)
        } else {
          $("[class$=" + year + "]").show(0)
        }
      };
      return $(el).not(".active")
  })
  .each(function(_, el) {
      $("[class*=" + $(el).attr("data") + "]").hide(0)
  });
});
```

```js
var filter = $(".filter");
filter.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  filter.map(function(_, el) {
      if ($(el).is(".active")) {
        var year = $(el).attr("data");
        if (!!$("[class^=" + year + "]")) {
          $("[class^=" + year + "]").show(0)
        } else {
          $("[class$=" + year + "]").show(0)
        }
      };
      return $(el).not(".active")
  })
  .each(function(_, el) {
      $("[class*=" + $(el).attr("data") + "]").hide(0)
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=button] {
  background: #fff;
}
input[type=button].active {
  background: pink;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.c2009 {
  background: red
}
.c2010 {
  background: green
}
.c2011 {
  background: blue
}
.c2012 {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="2009" data="c2009" />
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="2010" data="c2010" />
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="2011" data="c2011" />
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="2012" data="c2012" />
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="Science" data="Science" />
<input type="button" class="filter active" value="Codeur" data="Codeur" />
<section id="container">
  <div class="c2009 Science">2009 S</div>
  <div class="c2010 Codeur">2010 C</div>
  <div class="c2011 Science">2011 S</div>
  <div class="c2011 Codeur">2011 C</div>
  <div class="c2010 Science">2010 S</div>
  <div class="c2011 Codeur">2011 C</div>
  <div class="c2009 Science">2009 S</div>
  <div class="c2010 Codeur">2010 C</div>
  <div class="c2009 Codeur">2009 C</div>
  <div class="c2011 Codeur">2011 C</div>
  <div class="c2009 Science">2009 S</div>
  <div class="c2012 Codeur">2012 C</div>
  <div class="c2009 Codeur">2009 C</div>
  <div class="c2009 Science">2009 S</div>
  <div class="c2012 Science">2012 S</div>
  <div class="c2009 Codeur">2009 C</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem is still here. Clic on `2009`, on `Science` and after again on `2009` and you could see a red div `2009 S`. It's not a good filtration because normaly `Science` is disabled.

Comment: What is expected result if only `Science` and `Codeur` are have class `active` ?

Comment: Nothing because there is no date precised